# VBScript to check if the computer is present in Active Driectory

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I want to know is there any script to check if the machine is present in AD or not. Like say i have a machine named XYZ and I want to check if this machine is in AD or not.

Using VBScript how do I do this?

I am new to LDAP.

Comment: This is not a just-drop-your-requirements-someone-will-write-it-for-you website. First try to come up with a solution on your own and *then* ask specific questions about problems you encounter. Hint: This is a common task. You are bound to find something between a hundred and several thousand examples on the internet about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your AD is a Windows Server 2008 or 2008 R2 take a look at [Dsquery Computer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730720%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Use : **Dsquery computer -name MyComputer**

However, you can try using [ADODB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Or this example : (**sample from VBsedit**)

```
' List All Computer Accounts in Active Directory
Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCOmmand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.CommandText = _
    "Select Name, Location from 'LDAP://DC=fabrikam,DC=com' " _
        & "Where objectClass='computer'"  
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
objRecordSet.MoveFirst
Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    Wscript.Echo "Computer Name: " & objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value
    Wscript.Echo "Location: " & objRecordSet.Fields("Location").Value
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example here.. You need to use the WSCript.Network

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/58aea18c-d5ff-48a7-bc76-5bd64183ba8c/use-vbscript-to-query-ad-for-computer-account?forum=winserverDS